# Cards 'are' or 'is' a powerful tool?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Cards is plural but tool is singular. What would be more appropriate to use? Are or Is?

Comment: Verbs have to agree with the subject; hence 'Cards are... but card is....; tools are... but tool is.    Here, what decides the number is not any part of the complement, but the subject.  Cards are a powerful tool. Card is a powerful too. Both are right.

Comment: @RamPillai Explained very well. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RamPillai You're also not supposed to answer in comments!

Comment: I have voted to move your question to [ell.se] where I have found about 150 questions already asked about the same thing.

Comment: Does the answer by snailcar  resolve the problem? ["It is" or "it are"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11305/it-is-or-it-are)

Comment: See also: [“is” vs. “are” and when to use them](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43518/is-vs-are-and-when-to-use-them)